# Angular 2 routing/navigation

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, angular2-routing

I have angular 2 ts app, where routs defined as:

```
@RouteConfig([
        { path: '/accounts', name: 'Accounts', component: AccountComponent, useAsDefault: true},
        { path: '/transactions', name: 'Transactions', component: TransactionComponent}
])
```

When i enter into browser: http://localhost/ the url updates with http://localhost/accounts and works as expected, however if I enter http://localhost/accounts it become http://localhost/accounts/accounts and fail.

What is wrong?

The backend -ASP.NET 5 which is refer to index.html for all unknown paths

```
   app.Use(async (context, next) =>
        {
            await next();

            if (context.Response.StatusCode == 404 && !Path.HasExtension(context.Request.Path.Value))
            {
                context.Request.Path = "/index.html"; 
                await next();
            }
        });
```

the startup section:

```
   public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseIISPlatformHandler();

        app.Use(async (context, next) =>
        {
            await next();

            if (context.Response.StatusCode == 404 && !Path.HasExtension(context.Request.Path.Value))
            {
                context.Request.Path = "/index.html"; 
                await next();
            }
        });

        app.UseDefaultFiles();
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute("spa-fallback", "{*anything}", new {controller = "Home", action = "Index"});
        });

    }
```

Comment: Try adding `<base href="/projectName"">` in <head> in the index.html file.

Comment: Already had it, so problem somewhere else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated**

I just noticed the useAsDefault option in your angular router config (I haven't used angular 2 previously). I'm guessing that is automagically add the /accounts to your URL. Try this config

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    app.UseIISPlatformHandler();

    app.Use(async (context, next) =>
    {
        await next();

        if (context.Response.StatusCode == 404 && !Path.HasExtension(context.Request.Path.Value))
        {
            ctx.Response.Redirect("/");
            return;
        }
    });

    app.UseDefaultFiles();
    app.UseStaticFiles();

}
```

---

What's happening is when you enter the route directly in the browser it is getting caught by the asp.net routing engine. What you'll need to do is let the runtime catch this route and not handle it.

```
app.UseMvc(routes => {
    // maybe you have some other routes.... or not
    routes.Map("spa-fallback", "{*anything}", new {controller = "Home", action="Index"})
});
```

What should happen now is that your initial page will be rendered by the server, and any additional JS will run on the route.

Comment: Well, I added that code to me startup and there isn't any changes, the issue still persist

Comment: could you post the section of your startup that defines your routes and other middleware?

Comment: added into the question

Comment: @nelly2k try the redirect and let me know if that works for you

Comment: Now it is always redirect to default route. So i'm entering /transactions, it get redirected to /account

Answer (score 0):

OK, the solution described there.

http://blog.nbellocam.me/2016/03/21/routing-angular-2-asp-net-core/